# Are there publicly-available non-amateur sources of TLEs other than Space-Track?

Tags: tracking, two-line-elements

As an amateur satellite tracker, and sometime reentry analyst, I am always anxious to get the newest tracking data for low-orbiting spacecraft. I have had to rely exclusively on Space-Track for the TLE info, and seesat (and other great online groups) for occasional updates that JSpOC can't catch due to sensor gaps, but I am wondering...

Are there other agencies/organizations (USA or other) that provide TLEs (or other equivalent info), on a regular basis to the public?

Comment: Seesat may provide data that JSpOC *doesn't* provide for more reasons than "due to sensor gaps". [How are military satellites with (apparently) classified TLEs still showing up on sat map websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18300/12102)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.leolabs.space/ is not public, but unlike the Russian or Chinese tracking databases, you can at least purchase them.